# n!/k! with long input only works for small numbers, how does it work for eg. n=20 k=19

Tags: java, math, long-integer, complex-data-types

Hey the method works for a few numbers, but often it just randomly gives out some huge numbers, i am a bit confused about the datatypes used, the result should fit in long, anyone can help?
The formula is n!/k!.

I try to get the right result which fits in long

```
public static long penguPermutation(long n, long k) {
    long fact1 = 1;
    long fact2 = 1;
    for(long i = 2; i <= n; i++){
        fact1 = fact1 * i;
    }
    System.out.println(fact1);
    for(long i = 2; i <= k; i++){
        fact2 = fact2 * i;
    }
    System.out.println(fact2);
    long division = fact1/fact2;
    return division;
    }
```

Comment: Which method? Please take the [tour], read [ask], and then [edit] your question to provide a [mre].

Comment: You write "it should fit in a `long`", but the code uses `int`s all over the place. Read your first sentence and then look at the data types in your code.

Comment: By the way, to get `n!/k!` it's more efficient to do `for(long i = n + 1; i <= k; i++)` instead of division.

Comment: @knittl, i changed it, but it still messes up numbers larger than 10

Comment: @k314159, thanks for your help, can you specify how i use for loop then, do i delete the other two or is it just instead of the long division = fact1/fact2?

Comment: You don't need to calculate `n!` and `k!` separately if you want to calculate `n!/k!`. Therefore you can remove the other two for loops. But first, why do you think your method doesn't work? It seems to work just fine for n=20, k=19. It doesn't "randomly give out some huge numbers" but the factorials of 19 and 20 are indeed huge numbers.

Comment: @Amvanyy not sure what you mean. Plugging in 20 and 19 gives "20", which is the expected result. How does it "mess up numbers larger than 10"? Can you give the input `n` and `k` for your "messed up result"?

Comment: @knittl for input penguPermutation(n: 21, k :19); i get k! -4249290049419214848 n! 121645100408832000, k!/n!= -34, it should be 420

Comment: @knittl do you know the reason?

Comment: It's overflow.  You will have to figure out a formula for n!/k! that doesn't explicitly compute n! or k! -- probably one that doesn't do any division at all.

Answer (score 3):

A `long` can only store numbers up to `Long.MAX_VALUE`, which is `9223372036854775808`. 21! is `51090942171709440000`, which is approximately 5.5 times larger. Consequently, the value stored in the long variables overflows and wraps around to negative numbers.

But you don't need to compute the full factorials, if you apply a little math:

Let's assume n=5 and k=3, this will give you the formula (1*2*3*4*5)/(1*2*3). This can be reduced by omitting the common factors 1, 2, and 3: (4*5)/1. This is the product of all numbers from (n-k+1) up to n.

The largest factorial that can fit into 63 bits (a `long` value) is 20!. Your problem is not numbers larger than 10, but numbers larger than 20.

So don't compute the full factorial, but only the product of what is really needed.

If you really must handle such large numbers, consider using [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), but be aware of the performance penalty.